# Find the volume of the following sets using triple integral

Tags: integration

It’s a example from my lectures notes. The solution from the note try to use the cylindrical coordinates method to solve the volume of a set.

Given that:
$$
P=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3:x_1^2+x_2^2\leqslant 1,x _3\in [0,1-x_1^2-x_2^2] \right\}
$$

I slightly modify the model answer and it shows that:
$$
P=\left\{ g(u):u\in Q \right\}
$$

$$
g(u)=\begin{pmatrix}
u _1 \cos(u_2) \\u_1 \sin(u_2)
 \\u_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
Q=\left\{ u\in \mathbb{R}^3: u_1\in [0,1],u_2\in[-\pi,\pi], u_3\in[0,1-u_1^2] \right\}
$$
$$
\iiint_P dp = \iiint_Q \det(Dg(u)) dQ=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1-u_1^2}\det(Dg(u))du_3du_2du_1
$$

**Question 1:** How do we know $u_3\in[0,1-u_1^2]$ ?

**My attempt:**
Let $x_1=u_1\cos(u_2)$ and $x_2=u_1\sin(u_2)$,
then $$u_1^2\cos^2(u_2)+u_1^2\sin^2(u_2)\leqslant1$$
$$u_1^2(\cos^2(u_2)+\sin^2(u_2))\leqslant1$$
$$u_1^2\leqslant1$$
And here is the part that I am confused about. Should I put the $u_1^2$ to the right hand side?

**Question 2:** If I slightly modify the same question to:
$$
P=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3:x_1^2+2x_2^2\leqslant 1,x _3\in [0,1-x_1^2-x_2^2] \right\}
$$
Am I correct to say that:
$$
g(u)=\begin{pmatrix}
u _1\cos(u_2) \\1/2u_1\sin(u_2)
 \\u_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
Q=\left\{ u\in \mathbb{R}^3: u_1\in [0,1],u_2\in[-\pi,\pi], u_3\in[1-u_1^2] \right\} ?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1: from the transformation $g(u)$ you know that $x_3=u_3$ and from the description of the set $P$ you know that $x_3\le1-x_1^2-x_2^2$, hence substiting the other coordinates of the transformation $g(u)$ you have that:
$$u_3=x_3\le1-x_1^2-x_2^2=1-u_1^2\cos^2 u_2-u_1^2 \sin^2 u_2$$
$$=1-u_1^2(\cos^2 u_2+\sin^2 u_2)=1-u_1^2$$
again, from the description of the set $P$ you know that $x_3 \ge 0$, and so $u_3=x_3 \ge 0 \implies u_3 \ge 0$.

Question 2: no, I believe you meant to put $x_2=(u_1 \sin u_2)/\sqrt{2}$ because this is the reasonable substitution to cancel the coefficient $2$ in $2x_2^2$, but even in this case you would have a coefficient different from $1$ for $x_2^2$ and so the trigonometric identity $\cos^2 x+\sin^2x=1$ wouldn't hold. You would have:
$$u_3=x_3\le1-u_1^2\cos^2u_2-\frac{1}{2}u_1^2 \sin^2u_2$$
which doesn't simplify your expression of $u_3$ as nicely as in question 1.